# How to remove material-dashboard-react text from initial route from material ui admin panel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, material-ui

when I start my react web application I get `localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react`
which i from route force to `/`
but this previous shown for some seconds till web app starts.
can someone guide in removing it.

I get this on app start

```
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.1..../
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /material-dashboard-react
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/aakash/Drive_E/Tech/frontend/public
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /material-dashboard-react/
```

I searched in full project for material-dashboard-react and wherever I finded that I changed that string. But still not going.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in the same issue. After hours of brainstorming, I found the solution.
You just have to remove "homepage" key from your package.json then default route will be only "/" prefixed with your server URL.